# SQLPlus doesn't find values with where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I've imported a CSV file to an Oracle DB table. If I'm querying the first ten rows with a few columns it's no problem as you can see.

[image]

But if I want to the value "EDEKA-Neukauf" in column "Firma" with the where clause it returns that there's no row selected. As you can see here:

[image]

Does somebody has a solution? Because it seems like the columns were imported correct

Comment: are you sure that there are no spaces in that string that is in the table that you are trying to search?

Comment: And try to use `where Firma like '%EDEKA-Neukauf%'` and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, the ```where Firma like...``` solved the Problem.

Comment: Glad that solved the problem.  Just so you know, it is best to post text, not an image, of your code, data, etc. to make it easy for folks to try your code.  And for me, my company blocks images on this site.  You can also answer your own question, so it is flagged as answered, and after you submit your answer, you can *then* accept your own answer, so folks looking for questions without an accepted answer won't see this one that has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the where clause has to be combined with like, this will look like: `where Firma like '%EDEKA-Neukauf%'` . Thanks to Albin Paul.

Comment: Just done, I had to wait 2 days till I'm able to mark my own answer as solved.